# Dynamic Column choices

Tags: lookup-column, column

I have a task to create a Document Library in Sharepoint.  I have done this several times.  This particular site have a bit of a complex index structure.  I am stuck on figuring out if it is even possible to do.  I have one column (called Folder type) that is set up as a choice with several index option.  I need to create another column (called Assigned) that is calculated display a choice of options based on folder type.  So for example:

If in "Folder Type" the user chooses "Administrator"  Then the column Assigned should provide a choice list of assigned choices. In this case a list of administrators to choose from. If they chose Jurisdiction they will see a list of the available jurisdictions to choose from.

I cant seem to get the formula right.  Please help, otherwise I am forced to create individual columns for each Folder type, which can get messy.

Comment: Hi @JuenFuentes if my or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the lookup dynamically requires you to do either client-side scripting or server-side scripting. From personal experience I would advise against this because scripts need to be maintained and creating them takes some effort.

With JavaScript an option would be the [Cascading dropdowns function](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns) of [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/)

> The SPCascadeDropdowns function lets you set up cascading dropdowns on
>   SharePoint forms. What this means is that you can enforce hierarchical
>   relationships between column values.

If you would [create new content types](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Create-and-edit-content-types-3d5d45af-608d-4183-8d51-073095fe0312#__toc220831191) you could however do something similar without programming.

> Content types enable you to organize, manage, and handle content in a
>   consistent way across your sites. By defining content types for
>   specific kinds of documents or information products, you can ensure
>   that each group of content is managed in a consistent way.

A content type can have many columns like Lookup or Choice. You would create a content type based on the Folder content type for "Administrator" and one for "Jurisdiction".

When both content types are [added to your document library](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Add-an-existing-content-type-to-a-list-or-library-9eeb0a18-b3ab-4801-ab61-d036bc8a7389#bm2) the user will be presented with a choice of one of these content types. After selecting a content type only the matching set of columns will appear.